# What's the equivalent of finally in Swift

Tags: swift, try-catch-finally

I try to use the error handling modeling in Swift2.

```
do {
    try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath("path")
} catch {
    // ...
} finally {
    // compiler error.
}
```

But it seems that there is no `finally` keyword out there.How can I achieve `try-catch-finally pattern` in Swift.Any help is welcome.

Comment: it's **defer** - one of the most important things in all of Swift

Comment: Except sadly, nobody seems to realize that the pattern people will have will also need to run code that might throw at the end yet defer has no capacity for this. What then?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you are thinking about the SWIFT 2.0 error handling to be the same thing as exception you are missunderstanding. 
This is not exception, this is an error that conforms to a protocol called `ErrorType`. 
The purpose of the block is to intercept the error thrown by a throwing function or method.
Basically there is no `finally`, what you can do is wrap your code in a `defer` block, this is guaranteed to be execute and the end of the scope.
Here a sample from SWIFT 2 [programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

```
func processFile(filename: String) throws {
    if exists(filename) {
        let file = open(filename)
        defer {
            close(file)
        }
        while let line = try file.readline() {
            /* Work with the file. */
        }
        // close(file) is called here, at the end of the scope.
    }
}
```

> You use a defer statement to execute a set of statements just before
>   code execution leaves the current block of code. This lets you do any
>   necessary cleanup that should be performed regardless of whether an
>   error occurred. Examples include closing any open file descriptors and
>   freeing any manually allocated memory.

Answer (score 22):

**defer** in Swift 2.0 is like a finally, that means swift ensures you to execute that defer code at the end of current function scope.
Here are the some points that i need to know:

1. No matter even guard will returns
2. we can write multiple defer scopes

Here is the example and output that demonstrates multiple defers:

```swift
func myMethod()  {
    print("Message one")
    print("Message two")
    print("Message three")
    defer {
        print("defered block 3")
    }
    defer {
        print("defered block 2")
    }
    defer {
        print("defered block 1")
    }
    print("Message four")
    print("Message five")

}
```

Output:

```
Message one
Message two
Message three
Message four
Message five
defered block 1
defered block 2
defered block 3
```

Answer (score 6):

What you are looking for is called `defer`. It defines a block of code that is not executed until execution is just about to leave the current scope, but it is always executed.

```
func processFile(filename: String) throws {
    if exists(filename) {
        let file = open(filename)
        defer {
            close(file)
        }
        while let line = try file.readline() {
            /* Work with the file. */
        }
        // close(file) is called here, at the end of the scope.
    }
}
```

For more details on `defer` have a look at the [Apple Swift documentation, especially section "Specifying Clean-up Actions"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

Answer (score 6):

read this :  [The defer keyword in Swift 2: try/finally done right](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-defer)

for example :

```
print("Step 1")

do {
    defer { print("Step 2") }
    print("Step 3")
    print("Step 4")
}

print("Step 5")
```

Output :

```
Step 1
Step 3
Step 4
Step 2
Step 5
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 2 introduces its own take on this requirement using the [defer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) keyword

```
defer { 
    print("Do clean up here") 
}
```

`finally` = `defer` in Swift 2.

Article for [defer](http://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-defer) keyword

Comment: "finally = defer" - Not exactly.  In a try/catch/finally in languages such as C# or Java, the finally block will be executed regardless of whether there is an exception. This behavior offers the benefit of being able to put code in a finally block that will be executed no matter what.  In swift, defer only executes after the current scope, and a catch block would be in a different scope. So it's not quite the same thing as "finally".