# What's the proper way of using Swift's defer

Tags: swift, deferred

Swift 2.0 introduced a new keyword: **defer**

What's the correct way of using this keyword, and what should I watch out for?

Since swift uses ARC, memory management is usually taken care of automagically. So **defer** would only need to be called for memory management for cases where using legacy low level / non arc calls, correct?

Other cases include file access, I imagine. And in these cases defer would be used for closing the "file pointer".

When should use I use **defer** in the "real-world"(tm) of iOS/OSX development. And when it would be a bad idea to use.

Comment: Maybe this will help you? https://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-defer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of finally in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974104/whats-the-equivalent-of-finally-in-swift)

Comment: thanks. But well, that's more theoretical. I mean from a practical standpoint. What are/should be the best practice for when to use and not to use defer.

Comment: @EricD. I saw that question/answer. I'm wondering about best practices. Let me update the question. thanks.

Comment: Be careful, because asking for best practices will lead your question to be closed as "opinion based". You should avoid asking for best practices on SO.

Comment: "Theoretical"? I see answers over there that are good practical examples.

Comment: But the only meaningful example there is to use defer for closing a file access. What about other cases where it would make sense to use / not make sense to use?. Thanks @EricD.

Comment: I understand, you want more different examples. I still think it's a duplicate but I've removed my close vote anyway as you think it's not. But as I said, you should remove the "best practices" part from your question and only ask factual questions, otherwise your question will be closed as "opinion based". :)

Comment: I/O stream and ensuring it is closed at the end of the scope is an example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The proper use of the `defer` keyword is within a swift `do`, `try`, `catch` block. Procedures within a `defer` statement will always execute prior to exiting the scope of a `do`, `try`, `catch` block. Typically this is used for cleanup, like closing IO.

```
do {

    // will always execute before exiting scope
    defer {
        // some cleanup operation
    }

    // Try a operation that throws
    let myVar = try someThrowableOperation()

} catch {
    // error handling
}
```

Comment: This is good data. So `defer` should only be used within these specific scopes? This is useful. My understanding was that it could be used anywhere in a function. And my question was where in that function does it make sense to `defer` and for what. And also, when/how not to use it.

Answer (score 4):

`defer` is nice to use if you access C APIs and create CoreFoundation objects, allocate memory, or read and write files with `fopen`, `getline`. You can then make sure you clean up properly in all cases with `dealloc`, `free`, `fclose`.

```
let buffSize: Int = 1024
var buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>.alloc(buffSize)
var file = fopen ("file.txt", "w+")
defer {
  buf.dealloc(buffSize)
  fclose(file)
}
// read and write to file and and buffer down here
```