# "Finally" equivalent for Swift?

Tags: swift, exception, try-catch, deferred, finally

https://nearthespeedoflight.com/browser.html

```swift
    func untilThrowOrEndOfTokensReached<ConsumedType>(perform: () throws -> ConsumedType) -> [ConsumedType] {

    var results = [ConsumedType]()

    do {
        while isNotAtEnd {
            results.append(try perform())
        }
    } catch {
        return results
    }
    return results
}
```

Double `return results` looks strange and I want to fix it.

There is a similar question:

[What's the equivalent of finally in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30974104/whats-the-equivalent-of-finally-in-swift)

It is recommended to use `defer` but this code won't work:

```swift
func untilThrowOrEndOfTokensReached<ConsumedType>(perform: () throws -> ConsumedType) -> [ConsumedType] {
    
    var results = [ConsumedType]()
    defer {
        return results
    }
    do {
        while isNotAtEnd {
            results.append(try perform())
        }
    } catch {
    }
}
```

`'return' cannot transfer control out of a defer statement`

How to resolve this issue? Or should I just remove `return results` inside `catch` block?

Comment: Add `return 0` as the last line? It kind of depends what the aim of the function is.

Comment: What are you trying you achieve?  As it stands it's not cleart in this sample code - you have a `try...catch` block that doesn't appear to be doing useful work, as whatever you are doing is then ignored and `0` returned.  You could just return `0`.

Comment: Also note that if it’s Java `finally` you are referring to then you can’t call `return` in Java either which kind of make your question even more unclear

Comment: To be more explicit on what the issue is here: that `defer` block runs _after_ the function body has already done its `return`.

Comment: a lot of people ask for addtional info. So I posted a detailed description.

Comment: Since you are ignoring the error you can do `try? results.append(perform())` followed by a single `return` statement.

Comment: Lots of people here don't understand the point of the finally block in Java, which is to clean up resources that may require closure etc regardless of whether an exception is thrown. This could work using defer except where the action that you wish to perform unconditionally is async as defer cannot contain async calls. Swift exception handling really should cater for this use case but it doesn't probably due to undeserved Java hate.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `defer` here at all. I think what you're looking for is:

```
func untilThrowOrEndOfTokensReached<ConsumedType>(perform: () throws -> ConsumedType) -> [ConsumedType] {
    var results = [ConsumedType]()

    do {
        while isNotAtEnd {
            results.append(try perform())
        }
    } catch {
        // Log the error or whatever
    }

    return results
}
```

This will return the `results` accumulate so far, as soon as the first `perform()` call raises.

Comment: it won't compile because `return results` is inside `catch` block and may not be executed